# Github Action - How to keep the quotes in the sed command replacement?

Tags: linux, sed, github-actions

I have a github action that run this job:

```
update_version_numbers:
  needs: [build_release_notes, build_artifacts]
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  name: Update Version Numbers

  steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
    # Find and replace version
    - name: Increment Version Numbers
      run: sed -i 's/version=".\+",/version="${{ inputs.milestone }}",/' setup.py
    
    - name: Display setup.py
      run: cat setup.py

    - name: Push Changes
      run: |
        git config --local user.email "github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
        git config --local user.name "github-actions[bot]"
        git add setup.py
        git commit -m "Bump Ikabot version ${{ inputs.milestone }}"
        git push
```

The job consists of replacing the version value of a file named `setup.py`.

Here is a sample of my `setup.py` file:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="ikabot",
    version="6.0.6",
    license='MIT'
)
```

This file contains a line `version="6.0.6",`. And I would like to change the value `6.0.6` to my new version received as a parameter.

When I run the action, the value of my file is changed but the quotes are removed:
`version=6.0.7,`

In console this command displayed as

```bash
sed -i 's/version=".\+",/version="6.0.6",/' setup.py
```

I tried using an [online sed editor](https://sed.js.org/?snippet=Kd7nq9) and I don't see any issue with my regex.

How can I ensure that the command does not delete the quotes?

Comment: Looks like that should work. What does your `setup.py` look like? Are there single or double quotes in there? You may omit the trailing comma e.g. `sed 's|version=".\+"|version="${{ inputs.milestone }}"|' -i setup.py`.

Comment: @Azeem Unfortunately if I don't include the comma in the regex, it is removed from the file

Comment: Not sure why it removed comma for you. The above command is works fine for me with your `setup.py` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to add an escape sequence to your sed?
Try it like this and check the output :

```
run: sed -i 's/version=".\+",/version="\"${{ inputs.milestone }}\"",/' setup.py
```